# Query slower after upgrade from sql server 2008R2 to 2014sp2

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

I recently upgraded from SQL Server 2008R2 to 2014SP2 and upgraded the databases to the compatiblity level 120.
This query generates a better execution plan with the old cardinality estimator (traceflag 9481 enabled): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy9skV1Ox
It only uses 269 logical reads on object2 and 3 on object3.
With the new cardinality estimator i get this execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJAnpXk_e
Unfortunately this results in 269 logical reads on object2 and 68688 on object3.

The server is configured for adhoc workload.
Even enabling the traceflag 4199 doesn't improve the estimates/execution plan
Why does the new cardinality estimator generate such a worse plan?
Why are the estimates so far off?
What could i do to improve it besides disabling the new estimator or using query hints?

Comment: Is this the only query that is being regressed ? I was in same situation where in 2014  our queries were being regressed, so we choose to use 9481 as startup trace flag along with 4199 until we migrated to 2016. You would need to make some hard choices .. choose 9481 as server wide trace flag or address the queries on case by case. IMHO, 2016 CE is much better and we did not see any query regression when we moved from 2014 to 2016.

Comment: No, this wasn't the only regression i encountered. It was just the most disturbing regression which i just had not the slightest hint why this happened. Rewrote some others (e.g. converting them to subqueries) to guide the optimizer to better execution plans. I had high hopes for the new cardinality estimator and expected improvements rather than regressions.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your disappointment with the query plan regressions that you experienced. However, Microsoft changed some core assumptions about the cardinality estimator. They could not avoid some query plan regression. [To quote  Juergen Thomas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2014/01/16/new-functionality-in-sql-server-2014-part-2-new-cardinality-estimation/):

> However to state it pretty clearly as well, it was NOT a goal to avoid any regressions compared to the existing CE. The new SQL Server 2014 CE is NOT integrated following the principals of QFEs. This means our expectation is that the new SQL Server 2014 CE will create better plans for many queries, especially complex queries, but will also result in worse plans for some queries than the old CE resulted in.

To answer your first question, the optimizer appears to pick a worse plan with the new CE because of a 1 row cardinality estimate from `Object2`. This makes a nested loop join very attractive to the optimizer. However, the actual number of rows returned from `Object2` was 34182. This means that the estimated cost for the nested loop plan was an underestimate by about 30000X.

The legacy CE gives a 208.733 cardinality estimate from `Object2`. This is still very far off, but it's enough to give a plan that uses a merge join a lower estimated cost than a nested loop join plan. SQL Server gave the nonclustered index seek on `Object3` a cost of 0.0032831. With a nested loop plan under the legacy CE, we could expect a total cost for 208 index seeks to be about 0.0032831 * 208.733 = 0.68529 which is much higher than the final estimated subtree cost for the merge join plan, 0.0171922.

To answer your second question, the cardinality estimate formulas for a query as simple as yours are actually published by Microsoft. I recommend referencing the excellent white paper on differences between the legacy and new CE found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx). Focus on why the cardinality estimates are 1 for the new CE and 208.733 for the legacy CE. That's unexpected because the legacy CE assumes independence of filters but the new CE uses exponential backoff. In general for such a query I would expect the new CE to give a larger cardinality estimate for `Object2`. You should be able to figure what's going on by looking at the statistics on `Object2`.

To answer your third question, we can get general strategies from the white paper. The following is an abbreviated quote:

> - Retain the new CE setting if specific queries still benefit, and “design around” performance issues using alternative methods.
> - Retain the new CE, and use trace flag 9481 for those queries that had performance degradations directly caused by the new CE.
> - Revert to an older database compatibility level, and use trace flag 2312 for queries that had performance improvements using the new CE.
> - Use fundamental cardinality estimate skew troubleshooting methods.
> - Revert to the legacy CE entirely.

For your problem in particular, first I would focus on the statistics. It's not clear to me why the cardinality estimate for an index scan on `Object3` would be so far off. I recommend updating statistics with `FULLSCAN` on all of the involved objects and indexes before doing more tests. Updating the statistics again after changing the CE is also a good step. You should be able to use the white paper to figure out exactly why you're seeing the cardinality estimates that you're seeing.

I can give you more detailed help if you provide more information. I understand wanting to protect your IP but what you have there is a pretty simple query. Can you change the table and column names and provide the exact query text, relevant table DDL, index DDL, and information about the statistics?

If all else fails and you need to fix it without hints or trace flags, you could try updating to SQL Server 2016 or changing the indexes on your tables. You're unlikely to get the bad nested loop plan if you remove the index, but of course removing an index could affect other queries in a negative way.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the new CE is using different indexes, both of which give an estimate of 1 row, hence the ill-advised loop join.
Are you in a position to update statistics on both tables WITH FULLSCAN? If that doesn't help, please post the table and index definitions (with only table/column/index names anonymised).

Asides:

The ObjectX aliasing in your sample code is very confusing, you may want to reconsider next time you need to anonymise, especially for a more complex query. AliasX for all aliases, with X matching the ObjectX, could be an improvement.

By the way, if you haven't carefully considered the consistent use of nolock, you may want to read this: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

Comment: The aliasing in the sample code appears to have been done by [SentryOne's Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer) and its "anonymize" feature. This is done intentionally to protect the innocent (or guilty :)) and not risk divulging sensitive/identifying information.